# Unable to start the storage emulator

Tags: azure

As title says I use storage emulator to do some azure test.

But it always shows Unable to start the storage emulator.

I have already tried run it as administrator, reset its database and so on.

It takes me about half day to use this.

My emulator version is the newest.

Update:I have found the 127.0.01:10000 port has been used.

How could I changed my port? Since I don't want to close the port 10000's work.

Answer (score 0):

> How could I changed my port?

Information about ports on which Azure Storage Emulator listens is stored in `AzureStorageEmulator.exe.config` file which you can find in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\Storage Emulator` folder on your computer.

```
<services>
  <service name="Blob" url="http://127.0.0.1:10000/"/>
  <service name="Queue" url="http://127.0.0.1:10001/"/>
  <service name="Table" url="http://127.0.0.1:10002/"/>
</services>
```

To change the port, simply change the port numbers there. You will need to stop the emulator and start it again for port number change to reflect.

Please keep in mind that once you change the ports you will not be able to connect to the emulator using the following code:

```
    CloudStorageAccount acc = CloudStorageAccount.DevelopmentStorageAccount;
```

Or

```
    CloudStorageAccount acc = CloudStorageAccount.Parse("UseDevelopmentStorage=true");
```

As it is assumes the ports are standard ports. You would specify your connection string like the following:

> DefaultEndpointsProtocol=http;AccountName=devstoreaccount1;
>   AccountKey=Eby8vdM02xNOcqFlqUwJPLlmEtlCDXJ1OUzFT50uSRZ6IFsuFq2UVErCz4I6tq/K1SZFPTOtr/KBHBeksoGMGw==;
>   BlobEndpoint=http://127.0.0.1:{newportnumber}/devstoreaccount1;
>   TableEndpoint=http://127.0.0.1:{newportnumber}/devstoreaccount1;
>   QueueEndpoint=http://127.0.0.1:{newportnumber}/devstoreaccount1;

```
    CloudStorageAccount acc = CloudStorageAccount.Parse("DefaultEndpointsProtocol=http;AccountName=devstoreaccount1;AccountKey=Eby8vdM02xNOcqFlqUwJPLlmEtlCDXJ1OUzFT50uSRZ6IFsuFq2UVErCz4I6tq/K1SZFPTOtr/KBHBeksoGMGw==;BlobEndpoint=http://127.0.0.1:{newportnumber}/devstoreaccount1;TableEndpoint=http://127.0.0.1:{newportnumber}/devstoreaccount1;QueueEndpoint=http://127.0.0.1:{newportnumber}/devstoreaccount1;");
```